# Join models with existing fields in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, a user model and a profile model and each has a field already called username.

I am trying to set up a relationship between the models by doing this in my user model:-

```
User model
has_one :profile
```

And this in my profile model:-

Profile model

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :username, :primary_key => :username
```

I was expecting that if I create a new user I would at least see the username value copied into a new profile record but there are no records being created.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Why would you expect a new `profile` on instantiation of a new `user`?

Comment: I assumed that if 2 tables were linked then when I created an instance of a user rails would automatically create an ID in the profile table. This assumption came from watching the tutorials where products and categories in separate tables appeared to get linked automatically. I may well have misunderstood this - does my config look correct?

Comment: Perhaps 'has_one' is confusing you.  What that really means is "can have one", not "always has one".  So no, there is no Rails magic that comes into play to make it 'have one'. If you want to ensure it is there you have to do the extra code to instantiate, validate, etc. as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks...that has cleared things up so I will look at how I reference the field in profile when updating user.

Comment: TBH, I would have to do some research to validate your configuration. I don't know why you're doing it that way, though. Why not just do it the standard way with `has_one`, `belongs_to`, etc.? Do you have some special requirements/use case?

Comment: I did it this way because the fields already exist on each table and I didn't want to specifically add a new ID field.